# SocialEngine 4 Sign In double process

Tags: plugins, module, signing, socialengine

I'm trying to create 2 types of Sign In procedures, because I will have 2 different types of users. Is there any kind of module or plugin to solve this? Or i have to create my own module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different profile questions for different profile types in the Admin Panel on the Profile Questions page. This will allow your users to select a profile type such as fan or band and then a different set of questions will appear depending upon the type selected. For more information about the Profile Questions page, please see: http://support.socialengine.com/questions/156/Admin-Panel-Settings-Profile-Questions